# SQL Key value table--select ids that have multiple keys

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to obtain records in a key-value table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `PROPERTY` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `key` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `value` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`key`)
);
```

I need to get all ids that have MULTIPLE specific key-value entries. For example, all ids that have keys "foo", "bar", and "foobar".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given updated question...

since you know the specific keys, you also know how many there are... so a count distinct in having should do it... along with a where...

```
SELECT id
FROM `PROPERTY`
Where key in ('foo','bar','foobar')
GROUP BY ID
having count(distinct key) = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `GROUP BY` to group and then check the group count to count multiple values:

```
Select 
    id
from 
    `PROPERTY`
group by 
    key, value
having 
    count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Not sure you want/need the value  in group by here. OP's ? could be interpreted multiple ways.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't specific enough in my question.  What I actually need is ids that have several specific keys.

Comment: Specific `keys` or just all duplicate keys?

Comment: @lmerry213 so a key could be `color` and it could have `values` blue and red.  (2) values same key for 1 id... in that case eliminate value from group by and you should have desired result?

Answer (score 0):

I f you need the id of all the rows for key,value count(= >1)

```
 select id from  `PROPERTY`
 where (key, value) in (select key, value from `PROPERTY`group by 
key, value
 having 
count(*) > 1)
```